# running php artisan : Class 'Route' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just took new project, and I'm running into a blocking issue.
When running `php artisan` without any argument it throws the following error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Route' not found
```

When running the website homepage, I have an exception and the stack trace found in the logs is the following :

```
[2017-07-17 13:07:07] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class 'Route' not found in C:\wamp64\www\myproject\routes\api.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(329): require()
#1 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(285): Illuminate\Routing\Router->loadRoutes('C:\\wamp64\\www\\S...')
#2 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\Router->group(Array, 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\S...')
#3 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php(71): Illuminate\Routing\RouteRegistrar->group('C:\\wamp64\\www\\S...')
#4 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php(38): App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->mapApiRoutes()
#5 [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->map()
#6 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#8 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#9 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#10 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php(71): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#11 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes()
#12 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php(28): Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->boot()
#13 [internal function]: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider->boot()
#14 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#16 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#17 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(539): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#18 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(788): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#19 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(771): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider))
#20 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider), 17)
#21 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(772): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#22 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#23 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(208): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#24 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#25 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->bootstrap()
#26 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 C:\wamp64\www\myproject\public\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 {main}
```

I'm very new to laravel, so that might be a newbie mistake, but I didn't manage to find a solution on my own. Can someone help me ?
Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**:
The culprit was a colleague who wanted to add a "features" array at the end of the `config/app.php`, and misnamed it "aliases". So everything previously defined was lost.

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: Can you show the code in `routes\api.php`?

Comment: Have you modified `config/app.php`? Removed either `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,` or `'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,`

Comment: Found the problem. It was indeed in the `app.php`, where a coworker made a mistake, redefining the 'aliases' array instead of defining a new one. Thank you all, very responsive community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  Thomas Moors, the problem was found.
In the app.php, what was expected :

```
'aliases' => [
[...]
],
'features' => [
[...]
    ],
```

Except instead of 'features' a mistake was made :

```
'aliases' => [
[...]
],
'aliases' => [
[...]
    ],
```

So yeah, nothing worked as expected. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

As I see this question has not been answered for over a month now,

Go to the file where you've used Route::method_name() and import Route class there by->

```
use Route;
```

This is common in App\Providers\AppServiceProvider@boot() that implements

```
Route::resourceVerbs([...]);
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've typed `Routes` instead of `Route`.
So pay attention to similar errors like this. Write well the sentences.

Comment: Damn, I had it wrong too. Thanks!